# How to correctly set domain for Instagram images in Next js if domain changes every time?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Domain example: `instagram.flwo2-1.fna.fbcdn.net`.
It is possible to set domain like this:

```
images: {
    domains: ["instagram.*"],
  }
```

Comment: That's not possible. Have you tried setting the domain to `fna.fbcdn.net` instead (assuming the dynamic part is `flwo2-1`)?

Comment: That also not works.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution till date?

Comment: I saw someone do it like this: `scontent-*.xx.fbcdn.net` for facebook images on [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39441). Maybe do it like this: `instagram.*.fna.fbcdn.net`.